# Find multiple subtrings in string that vary slightly

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to parse through various strings that look like this

cpd00015_c + cpd00041_c + cpd00095_c --> 2.0 cpd00001_c + cpd00009_c + cpd00067_c

Right now I have code that finds the first instance, but I want to find all the instances of these.

```
try:
found = re.search('cpd(.+?)_c', reactionEquation).group(1)
print(found)
except AttributeError:
# AAA, ZZZ not found in the original string
pass # apply your error handling
```

the re.search function only finds the first instance of this. Is there a research for multiple strings that you don't fully know the name of?

Answer (score 0):

To get all matches use `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = "cpd00015_c + cpd00041_c + cpd00095_c --> 2.0 cpd00001_c + cpd00009_c + cpd00067_c"
print( re.findall("cpd(.+?)_c", s) )
```

**Output:**

```
['00015', '00041', '00095', '00001', '00009', '00067']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to update `search` to `find all`  and remove group.

```
import re
try:
    found_all = re.findall('cpd(.+?)_c', reactionEquation)
    for found in found_all : 
        print(found)
except AttributeError:
    # AAA, ZZZ not found in the original string
    pass # apply your error handling
```